# How to add item to a combobox?

Tags: mfc, combobox

I am a newbie to MFC.
I don't know how to add values to a combobox.
I have a vector class.

This is my code.

```
CellPhone cp;
vector<CellPhone> cellPhoneList;
cellPhoneList = cp.loadCellPhone();

m_pComboBox.SetCurSel(0);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<cellPhoneList.size(); i++)
{

  CString str = cellPhoneList[i].getSerialNumber();
  m_pComboBox.AddString(str);

}
```

serialNumber's type is CString.

combobox does not show serialNumber list.

how can I do?

Comment: you should elaborate your question to show what the problem is, since AddString is the correct way of adding string to the CComboBox

Comment: How you add your **m_pComboBox** and Where you add this  part of code ? you must do it at least in **OnInitDialog** after control has been registred/loaded (or after DDX_Control), otherwise it will not works.

Answer (score 0):

The **m_p** ComboBox variable name suggests that this is a member pointer reference. Perhaps you meant to use:

```
m_pComboBox->SetCurSel(0);
```

and

```
m_pComboBox->AddString(str);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to convert your `.getSerialNumber()` to a string in first place.